# Android Sync Adapter not working

Tags: android, mobile

I have developed a sync app, all is working well but just one problem.

```
public static void addContact(Context context, MyContact contact) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    resolver.delete(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?", new String[]{AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE});
```

"MyContact contact" does not work, it displays false every time i call it for example if i call contact.name it will return false

this is how I send Contact information

```
for (int i = 0; i < mtcontacts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject mycontacts = mtcontacts.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = mycontacts.getString("name");
                                String id = mycontacts.getString("id");
                                String email = mycontacts.getString("email");
                                String company = mycontacts.getString("company");
                                String job = mycontacts.getString("job");
                                String phone = mycontacts.getString("phone");
                                String fax = mycontacts.getString("fax");
                                String mobile = mycontacts.getString("mobile");
                                String website = mycontacts.getString("website");
                                String address = mycontacts.getString("street");

                                ContactsManager.addContact(NewActivity.this, new MyContact(name, email, mobile, company, job, phone, fax, website, address));
```

And MyContact looks like this

```
public String name;
public String email;
public String company;
public String job;
public String mobile;
public String phone;
public String website;
public String address;
public String fax;
public long id;

public MyContact(String address, String email, String mobile, String company, String job, String phone, String fax, String website, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.website = website;
    this.job = job;
    this.company = company;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.fax = fax;
}
```

}

Does anyone have any idea how I can make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved all i needed to do was rename my Strings

```
...
public String name;
public String email;
public String phone;

public MyContact(String address1, String email1, String name1) {
this.name = name1;
this.phone = phone1;
this.email = email1;
}
...
```